# Controlling for FDR in a GEE model in R

Tags: r, regression

I'm currently working on some regression models using GEE in R, and I need help with controlling for FDR.
**This is my model:**

---

regulate.gee.mother<-geeglm(regulate_emotions ~ sm_info + sm_share_compare + household_income + ethnicity,
id = fid, corstr = "ind",
data = na.omit(data[data$parent=="Mother",c("regulate_emotions", "sm_info", "sm_share_compare", "household_income", "ethnicity", "fid")]))

---

Where "regulate_emotions" is the response variable, "sm_info" and "sm_share_compare" are the explanatory variables, and "household_income" and "ethnicity" are the covariates.

I've tried two ways of adjusting for FDR.
**One way (using fuzzysim package):**
FDR(data = data, sp.cols= 25, var.cols = c(9,10,22,24))

This method produces adjusted p-values along with the statement
"Using generalized linear models of family 'Gamma'"
I'm not sure if this is the right fit in terms of the model as I'm doing GEE models for my analysis.

**Second way:**
summary(regulate.gee.mother2, test = adjusted("fdr"))

But there aren't any changes in the p-values this way, so I'm not sure if it actually worked and adjusted for FDR.

Please let me know what I need to change or if there is any better way to do this. Thanks so much!

-Mina